# Form not being posted when a file is attached (xamp localhost)

Tags: php, html, forms, form-data

I have a strange issue where a form is posted correctly when the file input is empty, but nothing is posted when I add a file.

My html:

```
<form method="post" action="create_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php echo display_error(); ?>
    <div class="input-groep">
      <a href="home.php" class="homeknopdonker">Homepage</a>
      <label>Product naam</label>
      <input type="text" name="product_naam" value="<?php echo $product_naam; ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="input-groep">
      <label>Beschrijving</label>
      <input type="text" name="beschrijving" value="<?php echo $beschrijving; ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="input-groep">
      <label>Prijs</label>
      <input type="text" name="prijs" value="<?php echo $prijs; ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="input-groep">
      <label>Afbeelding</label>
      <input type="file" name="afbeelding" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="input-groep">
      <button type="submit" class="homeknopdonker" name="register_product"> + Maak product aan</button>
      <a href="edit_product.php" class="rightsidedark">Terug naar producten</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form without any values, I can see in my network tab the following:

```
product_naam: 
beschrijving: 
prijs: 
afbeelding: (binary)
```

Above data is inside `Form Data`

However if I attach a file (small image) to the `afbeelding` input (file) the `Form Data` dissapears entirely from my network tab when I post it. The paramaters are nowhere to be seen and I get no errors when I turn on error_reporting.

What could be causing this?

Comment: In `create_product.php` would you do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and show us the output please

Comment: You use the term FormData, that usually goes along with submitting the form using javascript. Is that what you are doing?